# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "list" argument must be an instance of Array. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions

Hope you can help me solve this, should be easy for a trained eye! (Not my case)

I have this Typescript code, to use as a simple CloudFunction

```
export const add2list = functions.https.onRequest((req:any , res:any ) => {

  const userId = req.body['UserID'];
  const firstName = req.body['first_name'];
  const phone = req.body['phone'];

  var req1 = http.request(options, function (res1: { on: (arg0: string, arg1: { (chunk: string): void; (): void; }) => void; }) {
    var chunks: Array<any>;
  
    res1.on("data", function (chunk?: string) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });
  
    res1.on("end", function () {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      console.log(body.toString());
    });
  });
  
  req1.write(JSON.stringify({ 
    list_ids: [ 'listID' ],
    contacts: 
     [ { country: "test",  //phone
         email: "test@test.com",  //userID
         first_name: "Test Testinson",  //first_name
         custom_fields: {} } ] }));
  
  req1.end();
  
res.status(200).send("OK");
```

The question is When I use the hardcoded data inside req1.write the script works well. When I try to use the data given in req it fails and I get this message

"TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "list" argument must be an instance of Array. Received undefined"
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

What I'm doing wrong? I'm quite sure that some arguments have a wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

Chunck is getting undefined and array of chunck need is optional try this and lets see

```
res1.on("data", function (chunk?: string) {
     if(chunck)
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });
```

Comment: Hi, @Syed it does not work, shows the same error!

Comment: Try to add console.log(chunck) inside res1.on(data) and see if chunck is undefined or not

Comment: Thanks @Syed chunk was undefined and had nothing to do with the code!

Comment: Yeah try to see error you will get to know from there keep growing bro <3